# Undefined name 'firebase' Flutter

Tags: firebase, android-studio, flutter

Hello I am trying to implement firebase authentication in my flutter app I am getting this error
Undefined name 'firebase'

Here is the code for reference:

```html
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:multi_purpose_scope/Animation/FadeAnimation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';


Future<void>main() async{
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
    final FirebaseApp _fbApp=Firebase.initializeApp();

    final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
    TextEditingController _emailController = TextEditingController();
    TextEditingController _passwordController = TextEditingController();


    gotoSecondActivity(BuildContext context){
        final mq=MediaQuery.of(context);
        Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondActivity()),
        );
    }
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {

       TextEditingController _emailControllerField=TextEditingController();
       TextEditingController _passwordControllerField=TextEditingController();

        return Scaffold(

                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                body: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: () async {
                        gotoSecondActivity(context);
                      try{
                        FirebaseUser user=(await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                                        email: _emailController.text,
                                        password: _passwordController.text,
                                ));

                        if(user!=null){
                                    Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(gotoSecondActivity(context).menu);
                                }
                            }
             catch(e){
                        print(e);
                        _emailController.text='';
                                _passwordController.text='';
                         }
        },

                child: Container(
                        child: Column(
                            children: <Widget>[
                                Container(
                                    height: 400,
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                            image: DecorationImage(
                                                    image: AssetImage('assets/images/loginHeader.png'),
                                                    fit: BoxFit.fill
                                            )
                                    ),
                                    child: Stack(
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                        ],
                                    ),
                                ),
                                Padding(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
                                    child: Column(
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                            FadeAnimation(1.8, Container(
                                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                        color: Colors.white,
                                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                                        boxShadow: [
                                                            BoxShadow(
                                                                    color: Color.fromRGBO(143, 148, 251, .2),
                                                                    blurRadius: 20.0,
                                                                    offset: Offset(0, 10)
                                                            )
                                                        ]
                                                ),
                                                child: Column(
                                                    children: <Widget>[
                                                        Container(
                                                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                                    border: Border(bottom: BorderSide(
                                                                            color: Colors.grey[100]))
                                                            ),
                                                            child: TextField(
                                                                    controller: _emailControllerField,
                                            keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                                                                        border: InputBorder.none,
                                                                        hintText: "Email or Phone number",
                                                                        hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                                                                color: Colors.grey[400])
                                                                ),
                                                            ),
                                                        ),
                                                        Container(
                                                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                                            child: TextField(
                                                                obscureText: true,
                                                                controller: _passwordControllerField,
                                                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                                                        border: InputBorder.none,
                                                                        hintText: "Password",
                                                                        hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                                                                color: Colors.grey[400])
                                                                ),
                                                            ),
                                                        )
                                                    ],
                                                ),
                                            )),
                                            SizedBox(height: 30,),
                                            FadeAnimation(2, Container(
                                                height: 50,
                                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                                        gradient: LinearGradient(
                                                                colors: [
                                                                    Color.fromRGBO(214, 0, 27, 1),
                                                                    Color.fromRGBO(214, 0, 27, 1),
                                                                ]
                                                        )
                                                ),
                                                child: Center(
                                                    child: Text("Login", style: TextStyle(
                                                            color: Colors.white,
                                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                                                ),
                                            )),
                                            SizedBox(height: 70,),
                                            FadeAnimation(1.5, Text("Forgot Password?",
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                        color: Color.fromRGBO(214, 0, 27, 1)),)),
                                        ],
                                    ),
                                )
                            ],
                        ),
                    ),
                )
                ),
        );
    }

}
class SecondActivity extends StatelessWidget {
    gotoRegister(BuildContext context){
        Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>Register()),
        );
    }
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
            home: Scaffold(
                body: Container(
                    child: Container(
                        height: 174,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                image: DecorationImage(
                                        image: AssetImage('assets/images/patient_list.png'),
                                )
                        ),
                        child: Stack(
                            children: <Widget>[
                                Container(
                                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                                    height: 128,
                                    child: Text(
                                        'Patient List',
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 30,
                                            color: Colors.white
                                        ),
                                    ),
                                )

                            ],
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () {
                gotoRegister(context);
            },
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
            backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(214, 0, 27,1),
        ),
            ),
        );
    }
}
class Register extends StatelessWidget {
    goBack(BuildContext context) {
        Navigator.pop(context);
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
            home: Scaffold(
                body: SafeArea(
                    child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40),
                        child: Column(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                    Stack(
                                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                                            children: <Widget>[
                                                Image.asset('assets/images/patient_list.png'),
                                                Text('Registration',style: TextStyle(fontWeight:FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 30,color: Colors.white),)
                                            ]
                                    ),
                                    const SizedBox(height: 10),
                                    const SampleTextField(hintText: 'Enter Name'),
                                    const SizedBox(height:10),
                                    const SampleTextField(hintText: 'Enter MR-Number'),
                                    const SizedBox(height: 10),
                                    const SampleTextField(hintText: 'Enter Phone Number'),
                                    const SizedBox(height: 10),
                                    const SampleTextField(hintText: 'Enter Hospital Name'),
                                    const SizedBox(height:10),
                                    FlatButton(
                                        onPressed: () {

                                        },

                                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                                        ),
                                        // materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
                                        // visualDensity: VisualDensity.compact,
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
                                        color: Color.fromRGBO(214, 0, 27,1),
                                        child: const Center(
                                            child: Text('Register User'),
                                        ),
                                    ),
                                ]
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        );
    }
}
class SampleTextField extends StatelessWidget {
    const SampleTextField({
        this.controller,
        this.hintText = '',
    });

    final TextEditingController controller;
    final String hintText;

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return TextField(
            controller: controller,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    borderSide: const BorderSide(
                        width: 1,
                        color: Colors.black54,
                    ),
                ),
                hintText: hintText,
                hintStyle: const TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black54,
                ),
                contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
            ),
            // textAlign: TextAlign.center,   // Align vertically and horizontally
        );
    }
}
class ForgotPassword extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
                home: Scaffold(
                body: SafeArea(
                child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40),
                        child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[

                        const SizedBox(height: 10),
                        const SampleTextField(hintText: 'Enter Your Email'),
                        FlatButton(
                            onPressed: () {

                            },
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                            ),
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
                        ),
                        ]
                ),
                ),
        ),
        ),
        );
}
}
```

I googled my problem but can't seem to find the solution to my problem. I do know that there is something wrong with my initialization but i cant seem to connect the dots and find out where am i going wrong

Comment: Where are you get this error?

Comment: @fartem when i initialize  this  final FirebaseApp _fbApp=Firebase.initializeApp();

Comment: @RishailSiddiqui please check my answer

Comment: Try to init a variable after Firebase initialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize your Firebase into your main method

First `flutter pub get`

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(HomePage());
}
```

Comment: Have you tried with flutter clean and then flutter pub get

Comment: @RishailSiddiqui then why did you marked it as correct?

Comment: See comment below for the correct solution. As far as I can tell he cant find the import for Firebase.

Answer (score 9):

You have to have the firebase core package added

firebase_core: ^7.0.1 (check the actual package version)
flutter pub get

and add the package to your code

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(HomePage());
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I fixed the issue by upgrading to a newer version of `firebase_core` (I went with `1.0.0`)

Answer (score 1):

Add 'firebase_core: ^1.7.0' to pubspec.yaml file. And then flutter pub get. problem will solved.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. Using `firebase_core : ^1.0.1` worked for me in Ubuntu.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31373559)

Answer (score 0):

As Shubham already mentioned you have to initialize the Firebase instance before using it - although it doesn't necessarily have to be put into main.
You can initialize it anywhere outside of the widget in which you are trying to use the Firebase instance.
Firebase lazily creates its instance (most likely via proxy pattern) because its creation is expensive.
Therefore it can't find it immediately after you are trying to reference it :)

Comment: i tried to initialize it and then refer it in where i am using firebase instance just like we do in other OOP languages but it is still giving me an error